# How to set current page dynamically in flexbook?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am using a Flexbook which contains 2 BorderContainer. The code is shown below

```
<controls:FlexBook id="book" x="20" y="20"
               width="100%" height="100%" horizontalCenter="0" 
               animateCurrentPageIndex="true"
               showCornerTease="true" animatePagesOnTurn="true" 
               activeGrabArea="edge"
               edgeAndCornerSize="20" 
               hardbackPages="false"
               hardbackCovers="false"
               pageShadowStrength="1"
               curveShadowStrength="1"
               pageSlope="0"
               itemSize="page"
               backgroundColor="0xC3D1D9"
               borderThickness="0"
               borderColor="0xC3D1D9"
               cover="{null}"
               backCover="{null}"
               showPageSlopeAtRest="false" 
               cacheAsBitmap="true">

<s:BorderContainer id="page1">


    <mx:ColumnChart x="0" y="35" id="ccMain" height="90%" width="99%"
                    cacheAsBitmap="true"
                    showDataTips="true"  dataTipFunction="{getDataTip}"  type="clustered" backgroundElements="{bge4}">
            <!-- column chart code goes here -->
    </mx:ColumnChart>

</s:BorderContainer>


<s:BorderContainer id="page2" creationComplete="productMainPg2.addElement(lineChart)">
    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{lineChart}" height="21" x="10" width="95%" color="#b1b7f4"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

This code shows page1 as current page. **I want to show the BorderContainer (id= page2) as my current page dynamically on a button click.** I tried setting currentPageIndex = 1, but I get a blank page by doing this.

Comment: What's FlexBook and why can't you look through their API or forums for the answer?

Comment: There is this function called turnToPage(index:int) available. But I am not able to disable the page flip. ie I want to jump to a particular page (page2) and disable page flipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a [Bindable] boolean property (i.e. `[Bindable] public var isShowingFirstPage:Boolean = true`)
2. Set the BorderContainer's "visible" and "includeInLayout" properties to be contingent on this value. (i.e. ...`id="page1" visible="{isShowingFirstPage:Boolean}" includeInLayout="{isShowingFirstPage:Boolean}`... for the first one, and ...`id="page2" visible="{!isShowingFirstPage:Boolean}" includeInLayout="{!isShowingFirstPage:Boolean}`...for the second)
3. toggle / change that boolean based on some input, user gesture, business logic, whatever and the two container's should display / update accordingly.

Comment: I tried this, but the entire thing gets hidden instead of showing the next page.

Comment: Can you update and show your code for what this looks like? Also which codebase are you using for FlexBook? Is it from "rubenswieringa"?

Comment: Without knowing your code it's difficult, but I see a "animateCurrentPageIndex" property. Try changing that to "false", and then incrementing the new "currentPageIndex" property. Don't forget to turn "animateCurrentPageIndex" back to true!

Comment: by using turnToPage(index:int, animate:boolean) I am able to jump to the specific page. What I want is that, the user should not be able to turn the page once he has jumped to that particulat page. I tried doing book.enabled = false, but that is not working here.

Comment: Then based on whatever user gesture is calling the turnToPage method (i.e. a MouseEvent.CLICK), just wrap a conditional to check and see if the user has already visited that page. If they haven't, then call method with the appropriate arguments. Otherwise, don't call them method. This is a business logic issue it seems.